# Ubuntu installation not proceeding after loading screen 16.04.4

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I wanted to install Ubuntu as second OS on my DELL laptop(8gb ram,1TB HardDisk space,250 SSD, i7-7700 processor and Nvidia GTX 1050). After I boot from USB, it gets stuck on loading screen after I select Install Ubuntu from the menu. I waited 30 minutes on the same screen but the installation didn't proceed. I tried both UEFI and Legacy mode. 
Please help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a GPU driver issue, when you're at the `GRUB` bootloader at boot time, could you select start Ubuntu and press `e` to go into command mode, then on a new line after all other kernel header commands add `nomodeset`? This usually bypasses the purple and black screens of death.